# How to make header, main content and footer on scroll snap to viewport?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

I have an Idea that i don't know actually how to develop. I would really appreciate your help.

Explanation:
I want to make a fixed Header that on scroll becomes smaller. Then i have a content section that is height 100vh. I have also Footer Tabs that i like to position inside the content section. When scrolled down the Header disapear and the main content is filling the whole viewport. When i scroll more down, the Footer appears. And if i scroll again to top the same happens reversed. So it is like a kinda section scroll i guess and snap to viewport height. Hope you can give me some advice how to handle it witd jQuery or JS. Here is also a quick sketch of how it should actually be.

[Page Sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Fjs3.jpg)

Comment: Could you put up your code so far - including your HTML structure.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp) post and the code below might help you.
I'm not usually the w3schools type, but with your question, posts like this are really helpful.

```
#tab-content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var content = document.getElementById("tab-content");
var sticky = content.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    content.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    content.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

Have a nice day, Chris